# The strcpy_s function doesn't work in my code

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

This function is supposed to copy a char[] into the allocated storage. For some reason the buffer is always too small for this operation.

```
str(char* f) {

    len = strlen(f);
    txt = (char*)malloc(len); //txt is a pointer to a char
    strcpy_s(txt, len, f);

}
```

Comment: `strlen` does not include the trailing `'\0'` character as part of its length count.

Comment: Or... use `std::string` and stop using `malloc` for string management in a c++ program in the first place.

Comment: Another way is avoiding manual `malloc()` and using [`strdup()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) if it is supported in your environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For some reason the buffer is always too small for this operation.

You forgot to allocate memory for the null terminator. An empty string requires space for one character (the terminator). A string of length one requires space for two characters (1 + 1). A string of length `len` requires space for `len + 1` characters.

That said:

- In C, use `strdup` instead.
- In C++, don't use `strlen`, `malloc` nor `strcpy_s` (nor `strdup`). I recommend `std::string`.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you include cstring library